# Cannot checkout branch after doing a git rm

Tags: git, github

I just made the following change

```
git rm -r --cached myProject/build/*
```

and pushed the change into my remote repository. I did this on a feature branch called `story1`. When I try to checkout my development branch (which this branched from) I get the error

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
```

and a list of file in the directory `myProject/build`.

Any ideas on how I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only removed the files from the index without removing them from your working copy. The second branch still has those files hence the message. You can use

```
git checkout --force [branch]
```

to overwrite local changes with whatever is in the branch. Or you can just delete the contents of `myProject/build`.